# How do I change the id in the url with Angular 2 ActivatedRoute?

Tags: angular, url, typescript, angular-routing

I want to change a parameter in the url without changing the URL.
[image]

I have this typescript code:

```
onRowClicked(event: any) {
    let currentIdPerson = event.data.IdPerson;
}
```

And I want to send to the URL the IdPerson, how do I do that ?

Comment: This depends on how your routes configuration looks like, which component contains the routerLink or the `router.navigate()` call.

Comment: If I say this: `this.router.navigate(['persons', currentIdPerson])` then it will replace the rest of the url that comes after the id, and I don't want that, I want to keep it

Comment: Perhaps you want `this.router.navigate(['/persons', currentIdPerson])`, but as said this depends on your route configuration and where the code is executed.

Comment: I have a config like this ` { path: 'persons', component: PersonsComponent,
    children: [
     { path: '', redirectTo: '0/identification', pathMatch: 'full' },
     { path: ':id/identification' , component: IdentificationDataComponent },
     { path: ':id/account' , component: AccountDataComponent }
     ] 
    } ` In the parent app-routing.module, And the `onRowClicked` code is executed from a child component

Answer (score 1):

Es6 supports location .go method 
So import Location in your constructor's  component from @angular/common module

```
constructor(private location: Location){}

onRowClicked(event :any ){
this.location.go(`person\${event.data.personId}\identification`);
}
```

Your question is a bit incomplete but I guess that's the simplest answer I could give you

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to url of activatedRoute.
Parse the path to an array. Replace the id in the array.
Join the array and replace the url.
"this.location" is a type of Location

```
this.activatedRoute.url.first().subscribe(url => {
            let path = this.location.path().split('/');
            let index = path.indexOf(url[0].path);
            path.splice(index, count, currenIdPerson);


            this.location.replaceState(path.join('/'));


        });
```